Representing permutation groups as equivalence relations
To each permutation group $G$ on a set $M$ take a binary relation $\sim$ such that $A\sim B\Leftrightarrow \exists f\in G:B=f[A]$ for every $A,B\in\mathscr{P}M$.
It is reflexive because $e\in G$, symmetric because $f$ is a bijection, and transitive because $\forall f,g\in G:g\circ f\in G$. Thus $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on the set of subsets of our group.
Can we restore the group having the equivalence relation between subsets of its domain? If not, which additional properties are required for our equivalence relation to correspond to a group?
Is the relation between permutation groups and equivalence relations on sets an "isomorphism" (bijective)?

Just to clarify, $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $G$? Does $M$ matter at all here?

@SteveD I've clarified the question.

Not sure the rules are clear.  If $M$ has $m$ elements then $S_m$ acts transitively on subsets of the same size,  but so does every group that has $S_m$ as a quotient.  Are you assuming that non trivial elements of $G$ act non trivially or something like that?

I assume $G$ acts faithfully, and you want to reconstruct it up to isomorphism (or you want the actual permutations)?

@lulu I don't understand your question: "acts transitively" what does it mean? I speak about permutation group, that is a group whose elements are actual bijections on $M$.

@SteveD I want to try to restore the actual permutations, if possible. Otherwise, up to isomorphism.

The full symmetric group can take any subset of a fixed size to any other subset of the same size.  That's what I mean by transitive in subsets of the same size

But I do think you meant to assume that $G$ acts faithfully

@lulu Yes, the same size (because permutations are bijections).

@lulu: Because it's a permutation group rather than a group action, we think of the group as embedded in $S_M$ rather than a homomorphism from the group to $S_M$. Essentially, "permutation groups" are groups with a prefered action. Permutation groups on $M$ correspond to faithful actions on $M$.

What is $f[A]$?

@Shaun $f[A]={f(a)\mid a\in A}$, where $A\subset M$ and $f$ is a bijection from $M$ to itself.

$S_3$ and $A_3$ induce the same equivalence relation on the power set of $\{1,2,3\}$, namely that two subsets are equivalent if and only if they have the same size.
This is clear for the empty set, one element subsets (action is transitive), and the whole set.
For two element subsets, given $\{a,b\}$ and $\{x,y\}$, the element of $S_3$ sending $a$ to $x$ and $b$ to $y$ will do. For $A_3$, if $\{x,y\}=\{a,b\}$ take the identity. Otherwise they have exactly one element in common, say $a=x$. Then $(a,y,b)\in A_3$ sends $\{a,b\}$ to $\{y,a\}=\{y,x\}$.
So we have the same induced equivalence relation, from two nonisomorphic groups (not even of the same size).

The association from groups to equivalence relations is also not surjective.
First, the equivalence relation must be coarser than the equivalence relation by cardinality; that is, if $A\sim B$ holds, then we must have $|A|=|B|$. As there are plenty of equivalence relations that do not satisfy this condition, it is patently clear that not every equivalence relation on the power set of $M$ could possibly come from a permutation group.
But second, even if we restrict to equivalence relations that are coarser than the equivalence relation by cardinality, we still do not get that every such relation corresponds to a permutation group:
Note that the equivalence classes on one-element subsets correspond to the orbits of the action; these orbits must be respected by the remaining equivalence relations. For instance, if we have an equivalence relation on the subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ that has $\{1\}\sim\{2\}$, but $\{3\}$ not related to either, if this equivalence is induced by a group action then it must be the case that $\{1,2\}$ is not equivalent to any other two element set, since there is no group element that sends anything other than $3$ to $3$. Thus, we cannot have $\{1,2\}\sim\{1,3\}$. But clearly there are equivalence relations that are coarser than cardinality in which $\{1\}\sim\{2\}$, $\{1\}\not\sim\{3\}$, but $\{1,2\}\sim\{1,3\}$. Such a relation cannot come from a group action.
Even if we restrict to transitive permutation groups so that all $1$-element sets are related, we still don't get that every such equivalence relation comes from a group action. Again, consider the equivalence relation on the subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$, coarser than cardinality, in which every $1$-element subset is related to each other, and in which we have $\{1,2\}\sim\{1,3\}$, but $\{2,3\}$ is not related to either of the other two $2$-element subsets. This equivalence relation cannot come from a group action: for there must exist an element $g$ that sends $\{1,2\}$ to $\{1,3\}$. If $g(1)=1$, then $g(2)=3$. There must also be an element $h$ that sends $1$ to $3$. Then Then $h\{1,2\} = \{3,h(2)\}$, and since this cannot be $\{2,3\}$, then $h(2)\neq 2$; therefore, $h(2)=1$, $h(3)=2$. Buth then $h\{1,3\} = \{3,2\}$, and so we get that $\{1,3\}\sim\{2,3\}$. That means that the element $g$ that sends $\{1,2\}$ to $\{1,3\}$ must send $1$ to $3$ and $2$ to $1$; then it sends $3$ to $2$, so $g\{1,3\} = \{3,2\}$, and again we get $\{1,3\}\sim\{2,3\}$, a contradiction. Thus, this equivalence relation does not come from a group action.
So not every equivalence relation on the power set of $M$, even those that are coarser than cardinality, even those that require all $1$-element sets to be equivalent, arise from permutation groups; and different permutation groups can yield the exact same equivalence relation, even if the actions are transitive. So there is no correspondence and the map sending (transitive) permutation groups to equivalence relations (coarser than cardinality (that make all $1$-element sets equivalent)) is not one-to-one and hence loses information.

Consider the case $|M|=2$. There are only $2$ bijections from $M \to M$, just as there are only two elements in the group $S_2$. But there are many more than 2 possible equivalence relations on the power set $\mathscr{P}M$. So there is no way each possible equivalence relation can map onto a bijection in a one-to-one manner.
You may find it interesting to list all of the equivalence relations possible on the power set of the finite set with two elements. Is there any way to map each equivalence relation to one of the two elements of $S_2$ that is meaningful? Perhaps in general there is a relationship between the number of possible equivalence relations on $\mathscr{P}M$ and the number of elements in $S_n$, and a way to associate each equivalence relation meaningfully to a permutation. But that's beyond what you asked.
